# Linked List implementation using C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am having trouble understanding something:

```c
typedef struct {                                                                   
    int info;                                   
    struct node* next;                                                                   
} node;

int main() {
    node* head = NULL;   /*here*/
    node* second = NULL;
    node* third = NULL;
```

What does that line `node* head = NULL;` do? Does it initialize a new `node` named head? Then why is the `*` there, my struct is `typedef`d as just `node` so in other cases while handling with data structures, I should use like `node head = NULL` in this case.

Later in this code, I have

```c
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

which, I guess, allocates the space for that node. And this part

```
    head->info = 1;
    head->next = second;
```

sets the data and pointer part of the head node. Did I understand this correctly?

Comment: Do you know pointers?

Comment: You'll need to have a good understanding of pointers before you'll be able to implement a linked list. You may want to take a step back, read up on them then revisit this problem.

Comment: Instead of jumping head-first into "competitive coding" take time to familiarize yourself with the fundamentals first. There are a lot of good C reference books and introduction courses worth using.

Comment: Just Started Competitive Coding + learning Linked Lists == slow motion train wreck.  Linked Lists in C are a never end cause of headaches even among professionals.  Take a step back and really study pointers.

Comment: Short answer - head is made NULL because it is pointing to an empty list.  As items are created then added to this list, it will update to point at the beginning of the list of pointers.

Comment: Further, second and third aren't generally a part of linked lists.  You usually start at the head and iterate through the list when searching.  You also often place newly created nodes at the front of the list using the head pointer as the "next" pointer of the new data and resetting head to the newest item.

Comment: yeah @user253751 i know pointers but i dont implement them too much in my programs and i have gone through the fundamentals but was getting confused with what is meant *here anyway guys thanks to all of you for the help and i would really try to make my concepts more strong :-)

Comment: i didnt knew that linked lists would be that hard @MichaelDorgan

Comment: If you know pointers, you will know what `node* head` means and what `NULL` means. Learn pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does it initialize a new "node" named head?

No. It initializes a *pointer* to somewhere, and instructs the compiler that this somewhere will then have to be interpreted as a "node" structure. So, for example, "head->info" will mean that the first two or four or eight bytes, depending on integer size on your machine, will be interpreted as an integer value.

Actually, the pointer is then initialized to NULL, so it doesn't point anywhere at all.

When building the list, you will create new nodes, and then *head* will be updated to point to the first of these nodes. Head being NULL would mean that the list is empty.

Answer (score 2):

> what does that line " node * head = NULL; " does ??

So, node* is kind of a data type that you have created using **typedef struct** code.
So when you do node* head, you are actually defining a **pointer to node datatype**.
Since initially no linkedlist has been implemented, the head will not point anywhere hence, it points to **NULL**.

PLEASE NOTE : **head is not a new node, it is a pointer to the datatype - node**

> head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(node))

Here, you are correct - we are allocating memory for a node type, but we return the address of the memory space and store it in **head**.

> head->info = 1;

> head->next = second;

head -> info is for storing the data value, and
head -> next , next is the pointer to the next node (if any) in our linked list implementation.
**next and head** have the same data type " node* "

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one reason of this seem to be difficult is that

```
typedef struct {                                 
                                              
    int info;                                   
    struct node* next;                           
                                               
}node;
```

is the definition of a Node and not the definition of a linked list. More on that below.

But `node* head = NULL;` declares `head` as a pointer to `node`, a structure representing a single node of a list. Inside `node`, `info` is the data part, and could be anything, like a pointer to a giant useful structure of data. In this case, just a number. And `next` is the
link part, and will point to the next node on your list.

In your program, as a pointer to `node`, `head` can point to a structure like that, having a data part, the `info` field, and a pointer to another node, the `next` field. Sometimes there is also a pointer to the previous node too, and it is said to be a double linked list for obvious reasons.

But this is not a linked list in itself. Just a pointer to a node, and it is now pointing to nothing since it has been initialized to NULL.

You can write

```
node my_node;
```

and now we have a node. `my_node` has two fields and you can write

```
my_node.info = 1;
my_node.next = NULL;
```

and say you have a linked list of just one node. And you can even make `head` point to it by using the operator 'address of', the ampersand, by writing

```
head = &my_node;
```

that takes the address of `my_node` and put into a pointer, well, to a `node`. This is what pointers are meant for.

Or you can write

```
head = (node*) malloc( sizeof(node) );
```

And allocate memory just the size of a node. And then `head` is not pointer to `NULL` anymore. It is pointer to an area of the size of a node and be used as such. You can now write

```
head->info = -3456;
head->next = NULL;
```

Note that in the case of a pointer you use the operator `->` to access the field, not the `dot` as in the example of `my_node` above, a local variable in you program.

You can stop reading now if is clear what `head` is, and the meaning of the declaration in your program. What follows is just a more complete example

## (An arguably more useful) Other Linked List structure

```
struct c_node
{
    void*           data;
    struct c_node*  next;
    struct c_node*  prev;
};
typedef struct c_node CNode;

struct c_list
{
    char*   name;
    int     capacity;
    int     size;
    CNode*  start;
    CNode*  end;
};
typedef struct c_list _List;
```

Note that on the example of `_List` above things can get more meaning. One could just write

```
_List my_linked_list;
```

but `my_linked_list` here has nodes, a parameter that you keep the actual size of the list, a possible limit of capacity, pointers to the start and the end of the list to make life simpler. And even a name.

When creating the list you set things up as in

```
_List* create_list(const char* name, int capacity)
{
    _List* list = (_List*) malloc( sizeof(_List) );
    list->capacity = capacity;
    list->size = 0;
    list->start = list->end = NULL;

    list->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
    strcpy(list->name, name);
    return list;
}
```

and create a list by just calling

```
_List* = create_list("My First 100 Nodes", 100);
```

Note that in this case the data is just a pointer, the `void* data;` part of the node structure, `CNode`, so this thing can point to anything, creating an abstract data structure, a container of things.

This is just a part of an example and the intent is just to show how (I believe) more clearly the purpose and structure of a linked list. Much more than just a node.